# Accessing array from inside viewDidLoad returns index 1 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `NSMutableArray` that stores values from JSON. I select a specific index from the array to display that value to the button.

That works fine and code that does this work is prepared inside the function.

When I call the function, for example, inside the button it works fine and returns the result I want. But if I call inside `viewDidLoad` it returns:

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

This is the code to display data to the button and my buttons are ten and my array has ten elements:

```
NSString *onemb =[[mobile firstObject]objectForKey:@"package"];
NSString *onedolar =[[mobile firstObject]objectForKey:@"rate"];
nus_dolar.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
nus_dolar.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
nus_dolar.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
nus_dolar.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
[nus_dolar setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", onedolar , onemb ] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

This is my calling function:

```
[self loadingHomePageData];
```

Comment: where do you fill your array ?

Comment: I fill my array : like this -(void)proxydidFinishLoadingData:(id)data InMethod:(NSString*)method
{
    

   if ([method isEqualToString:@"getmobiledata"])
    {
         NSMutableDictionary * defaultDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [defaultDict addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil]];
        NSLog(@"%@",defaultDict);
    [mobile addObjectsFromArray:[[defaultDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"data"]];
    }
}

Comment: mr  arash please guide me

Comment: the error occurred due to you tried to access value at index 1 that doesn't exist. Check if the array is not empty & index is < array.count

Comment: my array has ten elements as I mentioned above

Comment: better you create sample project and provide url for the same

Answer (score 0):

The function that calls API to get json from server is ***asynchronous*** then it takes little time to get the response, and it won't get it in `viewDidLoad` life cycle.

You can use `@escaping completionHandler` (in swift- you should convert it to objective-c) to simulate synchronized method for getting response. and then you can use it in `viewDidLoad`.

see [How does a completion handler work on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18291887/7629882)

Comment: I get how it works but  still I no idea how to apply my problem by using @escaping completionHandler please guide how to apply to solve the problem I new to iOS. my code is in objective c

Answer (score 0):

If you fetch your JSON from a server, you can use this

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"anUrl"];

[session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    // your JSON parsing code here
}];
```